# Java rest web services return me a 404 using Postman

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

During the last two days I have been trying to learn more about REST web services and implement my own first web service by looking at this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm).

I am using Tomcat 9, the latest version of Eclipse for Java EE to create a Dynamic Web Application and Jersey 2.27.

What I did, after creating the package (following the tutorial in the link above), was:

1. created the package with the name: `com.usermanagement`
2. in that package I created my classes: `User`, `UserDao` and `UserService` just equal to the ones provided in the tutorial.
3. copied the jar files in the downloaded jersey 2.27 zip folder to the WEB-INF, lib folder
4. created my web.xml file that can be seen below.

   ```xml
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
   <web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns = 
   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id = "WebApp_ID" version 
   = "3.0"> 
      <display-name>User Management</display-name> 
      <servlet> 
         <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
         <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
         <init-param> 
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
            <param-value>com.usermanagement</param-value> 
         </init-param> 
      </servlet> 
      <servlet-mapping> 
         <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
         <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
      </servlet-mapping>   
   </web-app>
   ```

This web.xml file is located in the WEB-INF folder.

Then I exported my war file and deployed it in Tomcat which was correctly running. I did this in two different ways:

1. deployed using eclipse's tomcat server instance
2. used windows service to initialize tomcat and deployed manually in the webapps folder.

To check if I did correctly I would go to my tomcat app manager and the `UserManager` app was correctly deployed.

The problem is when I use postman to do a GET request it returns me a 404 error (see image below).

[image: 404 error]

I have lost the entire day yesterday trying to fix this and already googled a lot for the solution but none of the presented fixes seem to help. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

My user service GET method is defined as here:

[image: User Service class]

Comment: Read your code. You mapped your getUsers() method to the path `/users`. Not to the path `/UserService/users`. (unlike the code in the tutorial, which has the `@Path("/UserService")` annotation on UserService). That's the beauty of text: you can copy and paste it. Unlike what you posted, which is an *image* of text. Post code as text. Just copy and paste the code f the tutorial, which **is** text.

Comment: add @Path("/UserService")  to your class

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Thank you very much for helping me out with this ! You saved me !

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for the edit and extra kindness on your comment. It is way more useful right now friend ;)